# Wildcards in DeployURL of Rolling File Appender in jboss-log4j.xml possible?

Tags: java, log4j, appender

In order to have separate log files for every application running on our JBOS EAP 5.0 we have one appender per application:

```
<appender name="EXAMPLEPROJECT_INFO" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/exampleproject/info.log"/>
  <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
  <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
  <param name="BufferedIO" value="false"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p: %-100m [%c{1}.%M:%L]%n"/>
  </layout>

  <filter class="org.jboss.logging.filter.TCLMCFilter">
    <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>
    <param name="DeployURL" value="Exampleproject.ear"/>
  </filter>

  <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
</appender>
```

So far all works as it should. Logs of Exampleproject.ear are written to ${jboss.server.log.dir}/exampleproject/info.log.

Now I changed the naming of the archive from Exampleproject.ear to archive name with version included, e.g. Exampleproject-3.0.1.ear.

Apparantly the DeployURL now has to be updated everytime a new version is released which is not very comfortable as you can imagine.

Does anybody know what has to be done such as that the DeployURL can remain the same for new releases? My idea was to set the value of DeployURL to something like *Exampleproject*.ear* or *Exampleproject%.ear* which does not work.

Any ideas?